# How to check if json is empty in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

it seems to be trivial question but how can I check if json being inside the file is empty, ie. looks like this `{}`? Can it be done with `jq`?

Comment: Probably the simplest sure way is to use `jq` with the `-s` option, and test for `. == [{}]`.  Other solutions that deviate too much from this will work in some cases but not others.